# make a loop of numbers in a Menu of Chakra ui in react js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, menu, chakra-ui

I'm trying to make a Menu list with Menu items based on the number of the stock that in the object I made ,
so if stock in the object is 5 , then I want the menu to give me a loop from 1 to 5 for the user to choose

```
 const productDetails = {
      title : "product title",
      stock : "5"
  }
  
 for (var i = 1; i <= productDetails.stock; i++) {
     console.log(i)
 }

    <MenuList>
            <MenuItem>{i}</MenuItem>
     </MenuList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using create an array of empty strings and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over array to get the number of `MenuItem` as there are in `productDetails.stock`.

> I've used `index` as `key` which is not recommended. You can use any key for each element.

```
  const productDetails = {
    title: "product title",
    stock: "5"
  };

  return (
    <MenuList>
      {Array(+productDetails.stock)
        .fill("")
        .map((n, i) => {
          return <MenuItem key={i}>{i + 1}</MenuItem>;
        })}
    </MenuList>
  );
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked but I do not understand the "+" and the "fill" would you please simplify them for me

Comment: `+` is used to convert it from `string` to `Number` type. You can also use `parseInt` here or `Number` also like `parseInt("5")` will give you `5` as a number type

Comment: `fill` is used to fill the value in the array. so `Array(+productDetails.stock).fill("")` will be `["", "", "", "", ""]` . The filled value is not important because you are not using it.

Comment: That makes sense now! , I'm sorry I know I'm asking too much ,
I've done many codes with map function but I never seen a map with 2 arguments , so i dont really get the use of "n" in it

Comment: also , if I'm mistaken please correct me , Array is used to  change the number inside its parameters into array right? or am i wrong?

Comment: dude, I've used `Array` because you have to return an array as JSX children if there are many children, so you don't have an array. You just have number `5`, what I've done is created an array using `Array(5)` and fill it with `""` so it will become `["", "", "", "", ""]`. and then loop over array using `map` to return `<MenuItem key={i}>{i + 1}</MenuItem>` for each iteration  where `i` is just index. Simple